# Prepending path for RequestMapping on all controller methods in a certain package

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application with multiple controllers in a single package.  I would like to prepend "/api/" to all @RequestMapping paths and am assuming it is possible to do so in one place.  I can't change server.contextPath because I have other things that need to be served from the root context.

Is it possible to do something like this using controller advice?

Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to inherit the request mapping (at least some part of it) on each of your controllers.  Checkout this answer for a good code sample:  [How to inherit RequestMappings in a Spring 3 MVC REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228772/how-to-inherit-requestmappings-in-a-spring-3-mvc-rest-api) .