# Generic Spring MVC Controller with Inheritance

Tags: spring-mvc, controller

Can I do the following in Spring MVC

Suppose I have the Base GenericController as follows with one request mapping "/list"

```
@Controller
public class GenericController<T>{

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/list")
    public @ResponseBody List<T> getMyPage(){
        // returns list of T
    }

}
```

Below are my two controllers

```
@Controller(value = "/page1")
public class Page1Controller extends GenericController<Page1>{

}

@Controller(value = "/page2")
public class Page2Controller extends GenericController<Page2>{

}
```

Now will i be able to access the url "/page1/list" and "/page2/list" where first goes to Page1Controller and second goes to Page2Controller.

Comment: AFAIK, annotations are not inherited, so this may not work as expected

Answer (score 14):

That's not possible and was already rejected, see [SPR-10089](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-10089). I think this would be somewhat confusing and in addition, it is very unlikely that those method behave *exactly* the same besides the different mapping.
But you can use delegation instead:

```
public class BaseController<T> {
    public List<T> getPageList(){
        // returns list of T
    }
}

@Controller(value = "/page1")
public class Page1Controller extends BaseController<Page1>{
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/list")
    public @ResponseBody List<Page1> getMyPage() {
      return super.getPageList();
    }    
}

@Controller(value = "/page2")
public class Page2Controller extends BaseController<Page2>{
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/list")
    public @ResponseBody List<Page2> getMyPage() {
      return super.getPageList();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think SPR-10089 does not fit this example, which should conceptually work. SPR-10089 will not "stack" url mappings on @RequestMapping on the class level. see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268643/spring-mvc-requestmapping-inheritance for a complete explanation.

Comment: In this example, should be ok to have a class level annotation, and method level annotations in the base class.

Comment: how would that work? for each of the resources you usually have a CrudRepository or a similar Service.. by delegating to the parent how would you get the correct repository? You will need to pass that as an argument somehow, which would be ugly

Comment: @robin It seems that this answer is out of date. Take a look at manish's answer.

Answer (score 8):

For those looking for something similar with Spring Framework 4.x, the class hierarchy provided by the OP is possible.  A sample application is available on [Github](https://github.com/manish-in-java/stackoverflow-questions/tree/master/15382345).  It allows users to view a list of books or a list of magazines as JSON.

Comment: Why do you say that the super type does not have the `@RequestMapping` annotation?  The super type `BaseController` does have the annotation on the `list` method which is what the first code snippet in the question shows.  May be you have a different requirement and got confused?

Comment: manish, you're right, sorry for wrong comment - I'll delete it and upvote ;-)
Edit: The solution works fine for me, so IMO this is the correct answer.