# How to rewrite URLs with Spring (Boot) via REST Controllers?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, url-rewriting, http-status-code-301, request-mapping

Let's say I have the following controller with its parent class:

```
@RestController
public class BusinessController extends RootController {

    @GetMapping(value = "users", produces = {"application/json"})
    @ResponseBody
    public String users() {
        return "{ \"users\": [] }"
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "companies", produces = {"application/json"})
    @ResponseBody
    public String companies() {
        return "{ \"companies\": [] }"
    }

}

@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "api")
public class RootController {

}
```

Data is retrieved by calling such URL's:

```
http://app.company.com/api/users
http://app.company.com/api/companies
```

Now let's say I want to rename the `/api` path to `/rest` but keep it "available" by returning a `301` HTTP status code alongside the new URI's

e.g. client request:

```
GET /api/users HTTP/1.1
Host: app.company.com
```

server request:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://app.company.com/rest/users
```

So I plan to change from `"api"` to `"rest"` in my parent controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "rest")
public class RootController {

}
```

then introduce a "legacy" controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "api")
public class LegacyRootController {

}
```

but now how to make it "rewrite" the "legacy" URI's?

That's what I'm struggling with, I can't find anything Spring-related on the matter, whether on StackOverflow or elsewhere.

Also I have many controllers AND many methods-endpoints so I can not do this manually (i.e. by editing every @RequestMapping/@GetMapping annotations).

And project I'm working on is based on Spring Boot 2.1

Edit: I removed the `/business` path because actually inheritance doesn't work "by default" (see questions & answers like [Spring MVC @RequestMapping Inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268643/spring-mvc-requestmapping-inheritance) or [Modifying @RequestMappings on startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37338209/modifying-requestmappings-on-startup) ) - sorry for that.

Comment: I've provided an answer that takes a straightforward approach to this question. If you would like to have a blanket 301 & location header on every request to your application, please let me know if you have configurations extending MvcConfigurerAdapter

Comment: actually as the project is based in Spring Boot, I only have a single config class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` and a bunch of other ones with traditional Spring's `@Configuration` which provide a few `@Bean` or `@Component`; only 1 of them is the `public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` to customize Spring Security.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found a way to implement this, both as a `javax.servlet.Filter` AND a `org.springframework.web.server.WebFilter` implementation.

In fact, I introduced the Adapter pattern in order to transform both:

- `org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpResponse` (non-reactive) and
- `org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpResponse` (reactive)

because on the contrary of the Spring's HTTP requests' wrappers which share `org.springframework.http.HttpRequest` (letting me access both `URI` and `HttpHeaders`), the responses's wrappers do not share a common interface that does it, so I had to emulate one (here purposely named in a similar fashion, `HttpResponse`).

```
@Component
public class RestRedirectWebFilter implements Filter, WebFilter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        ServletServerHttpRequest request = new ServletServerHttpRequest((HttpServletRequest) servletRequest);
        ServletServerHttpResponse response = new ServletServerHttpResponse((HttpServletResponse) servletResponse);

        if (actualFilter(request, adapt(response))) {
            chain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        if (actualFilter(exchange.getRequest(), adapt(exchange.getResponse()))) {
            return chain.filter(exchange);
        } else {
            return Mono.empty();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Actual filtering.
     * 
     * @param request
     * @param response
     * @return boolean flag specifying if filter chaining should continue.
     */
    private boolean actualFilter(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response) {
        URI uri = request.getURI();
        String path = uri.getPath();
        if (path.startsWith("/api/")) {
            String newPath = path.replaceFirst("/api/", "/rest/");
            URI location = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUri(uri).replacePath(newPath).build().toUri();
            response.getHeaders().setLocation(location);
            response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
            response.flush();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    interface HttpResponse extends HttpMessage {

        void setStatusCode(HttpStatus status);

        void flush();

    }

    private HttpResponse adapt(ServletServerHttpResponse response) {
        return new HttpResponse() {
            public HttpHeaders getHeaders() {
                return response.getHeaders();
            }

            public void setStatusCode(HttpStatus status) {
                response.setStatusCode(status);
            }

            public void flush() {
                response.close();
            }
        };
    }

    private HttpResponse adapt(org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpResponse response) {
        return new HttpResponse() {
            public HttpHeaders getHeaders() {
                return response.getHeaders();
            }

            public void setStatusCode(HttpStatus status) {
                response.setStatusCode(status);
            }

            public void flush() {
                response.setComplete();
            }
        };
    }

}
```

Comment: doFilter() and filter() don't get examined together per one request.

Comment: @BrendanKim sure... but each method implements a different interface (as I explained in my 1st sentence) - depending of your SB context (Reactive or Non-Reactive)

Answer (score 0):

Since it looks like you want to preserve the 301 but also have it return a response, you do have the option to wire in your `RootController` into your `LegacyRootController`

That way you can provide reuse the logic you have in the `RootController` but return different response codes and serve different paths on your `LegacyRootController`

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "api")
public class LegacyRootController {
    
     private final RootController rootController;
     
     public LegacyRootController(RootController rootController) { 
         this.rootController = rootController;
     }

     @GetMapping(value = "users", produces = {"application/json"})
     @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.MOVED_PERMANENTLY) // Respond 301
     @ResponseBody
     public String users() {
        return rootController.users(); // Use rootController to provide appropriate response. 
     }

     @GetMapping(value = "companies", produces = {"application/json"})
     @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.MOVED_PERMANENTLY)
     @ResponseBody
     public String companies() {
         return rootController.companies();
     }
}
```

This will allow you to serve `/api/users` to serve up a response with a 301, while also allowing you to serve `/rest/users` with your standard response.

If you would like to add the Location headers, you can have your `LegacyRootController` return a `ResponseEntity` to provide the body, code and header values.

```
@GetMapping(value = "users", produces = {"application/json"})
public ResponseEntity<String> users() {
    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    responseHeaders.setLocation("...");
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(rootController.users(), responseHeaders, HttpStatus.MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
}
```

If you want to serve multiple endpoints that does not serve different status codes, you can simply provide multiple paths

`@RequestMapping(path = {"api", "rest"})`

Comment: If you would like to add a blanket 301 on all requests on your `api` path, you can register an interceptor to provide the response status and headers with a `HandlerInterceptor`

Comment: thanks @shinjw for your answer; I can see your point, however there's a few difference to what I want/what can be done: 1. I do not necessarily want to serve the JSON response for the "old" /api endpoints, and 2. both RootController and LegacyRootController are empty: they do not hold the code, while e.g. BusinessController does.

Comment: Moreover, your suggestion using an Interceptor might be interesting, although I'll need to figure out how to check whether the URI are supposed to exist or not; I mean I wouldn't answer a `301` with `Location: /rest/nonsense` to request `GET /api/nonsense`...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31082981/spring-boot-adding-http-request-interceptors for some inspiration

Comment: thanks, especially this answer or the following one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55901453/666414