# Spring MVC (Spring Boot) - RequestMapping inheritance

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, request-mapping

**Edit**: please read the question curefully, I don't need answers that repeat what I wrote.

Looking aroung the web I found quite a confusion about this subject.
What I'm looking for is a nice way to extend the value of a `Controller`'s `RequestMapping` annotation.

Such as:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class ApiController {}

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/dashboard")
public class DashboardApiController extends ApiController {}
```

The result should be `("/api/dashboard")`.

This approach apparently simply override the `RequestMapping` value.
A working approach may be to **not** put a RequestMapping annotation on the derived class.

```
@Controller
public class DashboardApiController extends ApiController
{
   @GetMapping("/dashboard")
   public String dashboardHome() {
      return "dashboard";
   }

   ... other methods prefixed with "/dashboard"
}
```

Is this the only feasible approach? I don't really like it.

Comment: this question already exists... https://stackoverflow.com/q/5268643/2736849

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring MVC @RequestMapping Inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268643/spring-mvc-requestmapping-inheritance)

Comment: @MuhammadFaisalHyder I know. We now have newer releases of Spring MVC and Spring Boot, but the documentation is a bit ctyptical as it has always been. Also, someone may have come up with a nice trick to solve this problem

Comment: Maybe have a look at this GitHub issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/16048

Answer (score 3):

This is not the elegant solution you're looking for, but here's a functional solution I used.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(BASE_URI)
public class ApiController {
   protected final static String BASE_URI = "/api";
}

@Controller
@RequestMapping(ApiController.BASE_URI + "/dashboard")
public class DashboardApiController extends ApiController {}
```

Comment: Good solution but I used ApiController.BASE_URI in ApiController annotation not BASE_URI.

Answer (score 0):

Values get overridden in the subclasses and not appended. You would need to specify the full path in the child class.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve what you are trying to by adding

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class DashboardApiController extends WhateverClassWithWhateverMapping
{
   @RequestMapping("/dashboard")
   public String dashboardHome() {
      return "dashboard";
   }

}
```

In this case it will be "/api/dashboard".

Values for the exact same parameter override on subclasses, they don't accumulate

Comment: this doesn't answer the initial question. `WhateverClassWithWhateverMapping` is useless in your situation but in the question it's the key for the answer