# How to set a context root for all @RestController in Spring Web MVC?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-web

I'm looking to define `/api` as the root context for all my `@RestController`s and don't want to specify it for each of them.

For instance, I would like to write `@RestController("/clients")` instead of `@RestController("/api/clients")` and make my request mappings available at `/api/clients` but have my static resources (in `/main/resources/static`) still served at `/**`.

So, setting `server.servlet.contextPath=/api` in `application.properties` is not a solution for my use case because the static resources will be served at `/api`, which I don't want.

In brief, I would like to have the same feature as JAX-RS [`@ApplicationPath("/api")`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/ApplicationPath.html) in Spring Web MVC, is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible <s>solution</s>(work around) is to use Parent Class with mapping

```
@RequestMapping(path="/api")
abstract class BaseController{
    ....
}
```

Other controllers can extend it

```
class OtherController extends BaseController {
  @RequestMapping(path="/clients")
  public ....clients(....){
   .....
  }
}
```

Please note that @RequestMapping will get overridden if you place it on top of any child class. Like explained [here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13882) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268643/spring-mvc-requestmapping-inheritance)

Answer (score 0):

Set the context root you want by using ***spring.mvc.servlet.path*** config into your application.properties.

e.g:

```
spring.mvc.servlet.path=/api/v1
```

Comment: not working with webflux